# Non diagonalisable matrix with diagonalisable power

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

**Problem:** Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix with real coefficients and let $k\geq 2$ be an integer. The fact that $A^k$ is diagonalizable in $\mathbb R$ does not imply that $A$ is. In fact, for example
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\0&0 \end{pmatrix},
$$
is not diagonalizable, but $A^2$ is the null matrix and is therefore trivially diagonalizable.

**Question:** Is there any non-trivial counterexample, i.e., matrices $A$ which are not diagonalizable and not nilpotent?

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: thanks @copper.hat

Comment: If the field isn't real but one of characteristic two, $\pmatrix{1&1\\ 0&1}$.